# Calling function from popover

Tags: methods, ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover

Alright, so I made a popover from my main view and all that good stuff. But I want to have my popover call an action in my main view when a button within the popover is pressed.

`MainView *mainView = [[MainView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
[mainView doStuff];`

The "dostuff" function changes some elements within the view. For example, the color of the toolbar is supposed to be changed. I've put a print command and the print command executes. But for some reason, the toolbar won't change color.

- I've imported the header of MainView into the popover.
- I did an @class thingy for MainView in my popover.
- doStuff is declared in MainView's header.
- The IBOutlets are declared too, and connected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you `-addSubview:` the `mainView`?

Comment: No, it don't think I did. Let me check...

Comment: Is it "[self.view addSubview:mainView]"? Because when I put that in my IBAction that calls dostuff, then the app crashes.

Comment: I'm now trying to call it via the delegate but it still refuses to work.

Comment: Hi user288225, did u solve this? I am facing the same problem. if u figured out a way, plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its disappointing that we have no direct method that can be used to check in which view (view controller) the popover is shown. The thing that I am doing in tabbased application is:

```
New_iPadAppDelegate *appDel = (New_iPadAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSArray *viewConts = [(UINavigationController *)[[appDel tabBarController] selectedViewController] viewControllers];
    MainViewController *viewController =  (MainViewController *)[viewConts lastObject];
    if([[viewController popoverController] isPopoverVisible]){
        [viewController doStuff];
    }
```

Hope this helps,

I know this is not the best way, hoping apple thinks about this issue, or if somebody has devised a work around.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: @Jann I don't know what you think but its the way apple also does see their refernce codes for splitview controllers http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH3-SW2